# Rejected Filter not working

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, filter, filtering

I have three checkboxes: Pending, Approved and Rejected. I am using the checkboxes to filter my gridview.

Here is my code for filtering:

```
    string sqlfilter = "id >= 1";
    DataView dv = new DataView(ClassBiller.FilterPendingConsumer());

    if (Pend.Checked)
    {
        sqlfilter += " AND (Status = 'Pending')";
    }

    if (Approve.Checked)
    {
        sqlfilter += " OR (Status = 'Approved')";
    }

    if (Reject.Checked)
    {
        sqlfilter += " OR (Status = 'Rejected')";
    }

    dv.RowFilter = sqlfilter;

    gvtransaction.DataSource = dv;
    gvtransaction.DataBind();
```

My problem is, my filter for Approved and Rejected is not working. Sample: when i check

(works fine in the first two sceneraios):
(1) Pending : the gridview will show the accounts with pending status, and it will show no accounts if there are no Pending status.
(2) Pending and Aprroved : when i check approved and Pending, it will show the accounts with the Approved and Pending status.

(problem)
(3) Approved or Rejected : suppose to be it will show the accounts with Approved or Rejected status, but what happens is, it shows all the accounts

Help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string sqlfilter = "id >= 1";
        DataView dv = new DataView(ClassBiller.FilterPendingConsumer());

        if (Pend.Checked)
        {
            sqlfilter += " AND (Status = 'Pending')";
        }

        if (Approve.Checked)
        {
            sqlfilter += (sqlfilter.Contains("AND") ? "OR" : "AND") + " (Status = 'Approved')";
        }

        if (Reject.Checked)
        {
            sqlfilter += (sqlfilter.Contains("AND") ? "OR" : "AND") + " (Status = 'Rejected')";
        }

        dv.RowFilter = sqlfilter;

        gvtransaction.DataSource = dv;
        gvtransaction.DataBind();
```